# Adding svg element with D3 in knockout and breeze

Tags: knockout.js, d3.js, breeze

I'm using [Papa John's Todo example](http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs02/) on a SPA. What I'm trying to do is add an svg element using a [D3.js pie chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636).

I can add the pie chart to the `body` tag, but if I change it to another tag it won't render. I'd like to add it to this id `#thegraph`.

*home.js*

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {

    var vm = {
        activate: activate
    };

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {

        // Do the graph
        return doGraph();
    }

    function doGraph() {
        //Width and height
        var w = 300;
        var h = 300;

        var outerRadius = w / 2;
        var innerRadius = w / 3;
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie();

        //Easy colors accessible via a 20-step ordinal scale
        var color = d3.scale.category20();

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("#thegraph") // This only works if I change #thegraph to body
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
    }
    //#endregion

    return vm;
});
```

*home.html*

```
<section>
    <div class="thegraph" id="thegraph"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you call the javascript before the html is rendered (do you include the javascript file in the header of the html page?).

There are 2 solutions for that:

1. Load the script that renders the graph after defining the tags (page footer)
2. Put your call inside something like `$(function() {...})` which is a shortcut for the [jQuery.ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

Comment: Kind of new to this whole knockout/breeze technique. So there aren't a place for this in the current setup of breeze? Can I still bind the svg object to the viewmodel (vm) so that I can use it like regular observable ko-object?

Comment: I don't know breeze or knockout. Sorry.